# How to count the most frequent value in a dictionary value that is a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like the following:

```
{'0013E139F1F37264': ['33984', '72190', 'V8909', '4019', '73303', '4011', '49390', '4019', '', 'V5869', '4019', '79029', '920', '', '', '33829', 'V1582', 'V5889', '72885', '', '', '25000', '25000', '', '', '', '', '78079', '4241', '', '', '', '', '', '73710', '', '', '', '', '', 'V5865', '', '', '', '', '', '73390', '', '', '', '', '', 'V5861', ''], '0014FFD71C90B753': ['36650', 'V811', 'V559', '73642', 'V5866', '', '', '4019', '2449', '', '', '72252', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], '00151A878F9A2C0D': ['4019', '38640', '73303', '7915', '36651', '73302', '8470', '78900', 'V7641', '42731', '7840', '', 'V5861', 'V431', '2724', '', '', '', '25000', '4279', '', '41400', '2724', '', '', '', '', '2720', '2859', '', '', '27802', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '71690', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '7291', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'V5869', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], '00157F1570C74E09': ['3005', '36619', '30000', '53081', '', '2469', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']}
```

This isn't like a normal dictionary because the values are in a list. I want to just count the most frequent value that aren't '' for each key. I can't use the counter method or really any other libraries within python. I would usually use counter to do this but am confused about how to move further.

My output should look like this (numbers are examples) :

```
0013E139F1F37264 : 2
00151A878F9A2C0D: 3
00157F1570C74E09 : 4
```

Comment: That is not a valid dictionary.

Comment: @rdas, it think bracket at the start is a typo

Comment: You can apply [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). `Counter(i for k in d.values() for i in k if i).most_common(1)`. It will return list with tuple containing value and count,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
test = {'0013E139F1F37264': ['33984', '72190', 'V8909', '4019', '73303', '4011', '49390', '4019', '', 'V5869', '4019', '79029', '920', '', '', '33829', 'V1582', 'V5889', '72885', '', '', '25000', '25000', '', '', '', '', '78079', '4241', '', '', '', '', '', '73710', '', '', '', '', '', 'V5865', '', '', '', '', '', '73390', '', '', '', '', '', 'V5861', '']}
    
test_list = list(test['0013E139F1F37264'])

filt = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', test_list))
        
result = max(set(filt), key = test_list.count)`
```

result gives the output of 4019

Explanation:

You first create a variable with a list type from your dictionary value and then use the filter function to filter the empty elements out.